# How do I convert the following range to text?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to change the following field to text like this:

0-250000 to '$0 to $250,000'

I have to do it multiple times. Is there a way to automate this? For a variety of numbers..

I have been doing it manually and it takes a long time

Comment: Does it need to be vba? This can be done via formula.

Comment: Any way is fine. Doesnt need to be vba. But need to be able to do even if there are different values

Answer (score 5):

If you have TEXTSPLIT:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" to ",,DOLLAR(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-"),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This formula uses `Find` and `Mid` to extract the various parts, then uses `Dollar` to format the commas.

```
=DOLLAR(MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1) - 1),0) & " to " & DOLLAR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1) + 1,LEN(A1)),0)
```

Comment: You can just use `LEN(A1)` instead of `LEN(A1) - FIND("-",A1,1) + 1` to save you another find. `Mid` will automatically truncate at the end of the string.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ nifty, done.

Answer (score 2):

If A1 conains `0-250000` then use the following formula in B1

```
=TEXT(VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)),"$#,##0") & " to " & TEXT(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),"$#,##0")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE("$"&A1,"-"," to $")
```

However, this would be inferior to `DOLLAR()` based solutions given the formatting of the actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel('split.xlsx')

data1 = data['ColumnA'].str.split('-', expand=True)

merge_value = "$" + data1[0] + " to " + "$" + data1[[1]]

data['Final'] = merge_value

data = data[['ColumnA','Final']]

data.to_excel("split_final.xlsx", index=False)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some explanations would be nice, especially as this is no VBA.